# How to connect C# to SocketIO using SocketIOClient

Tags: c#, socket.io

How to connect C# to SocketIO using SocketIOClient ? I'm using C# for connect SocketIO using SocketIOClient .. My backend using express Js .. im using this library for client
`https://github.com/Quobject/SocketIoClientDotNet`

this is my code (**Server App**)

```
req.io.emit('newData', { data: data.dataValues })
```

this is my code (**Client App**)

```
using Quobject.SocketIoClientDotNet.Client;

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var socket = IO.Socket("http://localhost:3000");
    socket.On(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT, () =>
    {
        socket.Emit("newData");
        MessageBox.Show("Connect.....");
    });

    socket.On("newData", (data) =>
    {
        MessageBox.Show("test.....");
        Console.WriteLine(data);
        socket.Disconnect();
        MessageBox.Show("Testing");
    });
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: What's the problem? The code above should work, right?

Comment: @GellioGao not respon , message box not show

Comment: If you test code here which look like you code (https://github.com/Quobject/SocketIoClientDotNet/blob/master/Src/SocketIoClientDotNet.Tests.net45/ClientTests/ServerConnectionTest.cs)  So your code is failing for one of two reasons 1) Your button click isn't working and you are not getting to the code 2) Your connection is not completing and getting an exception.  I would add an exception handler the will output an error if you are getting an exception.